# Install4j code signing for MacOS is not working

Tags: macos, install4j

We are building a Mac OSX installer (installer type as 'Mac OSX Folder') and signing it with a Developer ID certificate. Provided the certificate path in the 'General Settings -> Code signing' and password of the certificate is added at .m2/settings.xml field . The build was success without any errors.

When verified the build in OSX 10.12 with 'codesign' command below was the output.

```
$ codesign -dvvv ~/Downloads/xxxxx_OSX-X64_1_3_4.dmg 
Executable=/Users/admin/Downloads/xxxxx_OSX-X64_1_3_4.dmg
Identifier=xxxxx_OSX-X64_1_3_4
Format=disk image
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=169 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+2 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=6e0ce9b3323f355070abf166b0d1da2dabddc2f4
Hash choices=sha256
CDHash=6e0ce9b3323f355070abf166b0d1da2dabddc2f4
Signature size=7237
Authority=Cygilant
Authority=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA
Authority=thawte Primary Root CA
Timestamp=Dec 3, 2017, 10:03:19 PM
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=36
```

When tried to open the dmg file, error displayed as the executable can't be opened as it's from an unauthorized developer. Did the application not signed properly using the certificate? Are we missing anything ?

---Updated----

When I verified the application installer (.app folder) at the mounted path, here is the output.

```
$ codesign --verify -dvvv  /Volumes/xxxxxx/xxxxx\ Installer.app
Executable=/Volumes/xxxxxx/xxxxxx Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
Identifier=com.install4j.xxxxxxx.2509
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=1203 flags=0x0(none) hashes=32+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=490399e96743dcca06dae7622afdb60e1adeab42
Hash choices=sha256
CDHash=490399e96743dcca06dae7622afdb60e1adeab42
Signature size=7237
Authority=Cygilant
Authority=thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA
Authority=thawte Primary Root CA
Timestamp=Dec 3, 2017, 10:03:03 PM
Info.plist entries=26
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=23
Internal requirements count=1 size=36
```

Does this mean the installer is signed properly?

Comment: "thawte SHA256 Code Signing CA"? I'm pretty sure you're not using an Apple Developer ID certificate. Also, the signature on the disk image is secondary; the signature on the app and/or installer package is the main thing. What's in the disk image, and how is it signed?

Comment: @GordonDavisson is right, you're not using the Apple Developer ID certificate for signing.

Comment: ok..we are using the certificates obtained from https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/apple/. Is this not the Developer ID certificate ?

Comment: No, Developer ID certs are only issued by Apple to registered developers. Also, note that different Dev ID certs are required for different purposes, e.g. signing installer packages (.pkg files) vs. signing apps and disk images. See Apple's page on [Developer ID and Gatekeeper](https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/) for links to the details. I'm not really sure what thawte's code signing certs "For Mac" are, other than generic code signing certs.

Comment: Updated question with more findings.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Updated my question with the signature output of installer (.app). Is the installer considered as properly signed ?

Comment: @HemanthAbbina Not for Gatekeeper (the part of macOS that's blocking the app); that requires an Apple Developer ID cert, not something from thawte.